# how to access data id from API for delete operation in react JS? data._id is not working ... need to accept api id for deletion of api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

```
const deleteHandler = async () => {
        await axios.delete('(http://localhost:5000/users/)' + editId).then((res) => {
            const deleteUser = data.filter((obj) => obj._id !== editId);
            handleGet();
            setData(deleteUser);
            setEditId('');
        });
};
```

need to accept API id for deletion of API.

Comment: is the "data" array a mongodb object?

Comment: data is array and we accept apis in that so i called only data._id but not working   (instead of editId i use data._id but not work , when i wrote await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/users/' + data[0]._id) then it work but only first element of array is delete

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the parentheses:

```
await axios.delete('(http://localhost:5000/users/)' + editId)
```

Should be:

```
await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/users/' + editId)
```

Also you can use it with backticks:

```
Should be:

await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/users/${editId}`)
```

You might want to pass the id in the request's body:

```
const res = await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/users', { data: { id: editId } });
```

Comment: not working returns 404 error in console

Comment: A 404 might happened when the server is not up

Comment: 404 error is page not found.

Comment: When you type:
http://localhost:5000
or 
http://localhost:5000/users
In the URL section in the browser, what do you get?

Comment: when i wrote  await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/users/' + data[0]._id) then it deletes first element present in array i need to delete others as my choice . then i try data._id but it not return any value